# change Person or Group to show Username

Tags: list, list-view

Im using Office 365 SharePoint, I created SSIS package the pulls data from SPlist to server, how can I update the CreatedbyID to show the Username. please give me step by step as I'm new with SP. NO JSON knowledge as well. TIA

Answer (score 0):

- Go to list setting
- Click on Created By column
- in additional column setting you will find `show field`
- Select `User Name` from drop down.
- click okay.

[image]
Go to list to see the effect.

Comment: I've tried that, but in SSIS it still shows the CreatedByID